# How do I use the 'dot' from number keypad without encountering a 'Run-time error 13'?

Tags: vba

I am new to programming 
How can I make my program to accept (`.`) entered from number keypad and not only (`,`) when entering a real number (e.g  `2.50`) to be used in calculations.
I always get a `runtime error 13`

Please assist

Comment: Is this a locale settings issue?

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always replace a dot with a comma or the other way around in a string if that is what you present to your program.
Example: newNumber = Replace(theNumber, ".", ",")